# Getting Memory Leakage - NSData conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I am getting memory pressure warning for my iPhone 4 with following scenario:
I need to upload my image to server and am using Amazon s3. I am converting my selected image into `NSMutableData` with following code:

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);

CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{(id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                                      (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                                      (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: maxSize],
                                                      (id)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:compressionQuality]};

CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options); // Create scaled image

CFStringRef UTI = kUTTypeJPEG;
NSMutableData *destData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)destData, UTI, 1, NULL);
if (!destination) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create image destination");
}
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, thumbnail,( __bridge CFDictionaryRef)metadata); // copy all metadata in source to destination
if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create data from image destination");
}

if (!destination) CFRelease(destination);
CFRelease(source);
CFRelease(thumbnail);

return [destData copy];
```

Why am I getting a memory warning after 24th image when I execute this in loop?

Comment: iphone4 already has very low memory, is it happening in other devices and are you open to use other techniques to upload image to server?

Comment: Thanks Saheb, Yes, only on iPhone 4 am facing this issue. bcoz i have tried with iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s also with number of images count likely 50+ images its happening properly. Is that possible to fix by memory level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are loading this image in memory as a whole , so its fetching a memory problem. Normally i would save the image to Document directory and then upload the image by multipart using the PATH of the image.
That would only load the image as multipart hence memory issue would not be an issue. I dont know if this would be applicable for the thing you are doing.

Please let me know.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however it doesn't actually answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

This code has a leak.

Specifically, you have a line that says:

```
if (!destination) CFRelease(destination);
```

That will release it only if it is `NULL`, which is the opposite of what what you intended:

```
if (destination) CFRelease(destination);
```

By the way, if you press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, Xcode will perform a static analysis of your code. It would have told you about this problem (as well as a few other problems in the code). It's remarkably good at finding these issues.

---

I might suggest something like:

```
- (NSData * _Nullable)processImageData:(NSData *)imageData maxSize:(double)maxSize compressionQuality:(double)compressionQuality metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata {
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);

    CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{(id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                                          (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                                          (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: maxSize],
                                                          (id)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:compressionQuality]};

    CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options); // Create scaled image

    CFRelease(source);

    CFStringRef UTI = kUTTypeJPEG;
    NSMutableData *destData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)destData, UTI, 1, NULL);
    if (!destination) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create image destination");
        destData = nil;
    } else {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, thumbnail,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)metadata); // copy all metadata in source to destination
        if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create data from image destination");
            destData = nil;
        }
        CFRelease(destination);
    }

    CFRelease(thumbnail);

    return [destData copy];
}
```

Comment: Logging failures but actually taking no other action will lead to disaster in that code as well.

Comment: Agreed. At the very least he should return `nil` upon error. See code snippet in revised answer which does precisely that (and fixes a couple of other issues in the original code snippet).

Comment: I'll suggest to add "Intruments Leaks" to help also find memory leaks. Because a memory pressure doesn't always mean a leak, and if that's the case, "Intruments Allocation" may help, because I'm afraid that the author thought memory pressure => memory leak.

Comment: If you still have leaks, that's a fine strategy, though I personally find that the static analyzer is a far more effective tool for diagnosing leaks in CoreGraphics and Image I/O code. And Xcode 8's new object graph tool is excellent in diagnosing strong reference cycles. But if you're still leaking after getting a clean bill of health from the static analyzer, then I agree Instruments is the next tool to pursue.